# simple program using libnetfilter_queue isn't working

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

I'm trying to learn how to use libnetfilter_queue. I've compiled the example provided with the library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>        /* for NF_ACCEPT */

#include <libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h>

/* returns packet id */
static u_int32_t print_pkt (struct nfq_data *tb)
{
    int id = 0;
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hw *hwph;
    u_int32_t mark,ifi; 
    int ret;
    char *data;

    ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(tb);
    if (ph) {
        id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);
        printf("hw_protocol=0x%04x hook=%u id=%u ",
            ntohs(ph->hw_protocol), ph->hook, id);
    }

    hwph = nfq_get_packet_hw(tb);
    if (hwph) {
        int i, hlen = ntohs(hwph->hw_addrlen);

        printf("hw_src_addr=");
        for (i = 0; i < hlen-1; i++)
            printf("%02x:", hwph->hw_addr[i]);
        printf("%02x ", hwph->hw_addr[hlen-1]);
    }

    mark = nfq_get_nfmark(tb);
    if (mark)
        printf("mark=%u ", mark);

    ifi = nfq_get_indev(tb);
    if (ifi)
        printf("indev=%u ", ifi);

    ifi = nfq_get_outdev(tb);
    if (ifi)
        printf("outdev=%u ", ifi);
    ifi = nfq_get_physindev(tb);
    if (ifi)
        printf("physindev=%u ", ifi);

    ifi = nfq_get_physoutdev(tb);
    if (ifi)
        printf("physoutdev=%u ", ifi);

    ret = nfq_get_payload(tb, &data);
    if (ret >= 0)
        printf("payload_len=%d ", ret);

    fputc('\n', stdout);

    return id;
}


static int cb(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg,
          struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data)
{
    u_int32_t id = print_pkt(nfa);
    printf("entering callback\n");
    return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct nfq_handle *h;
    struct nfq_q_handle *qh;
    int fd;
    int rv;
    char buf[4096] __attribute__ ((aligned));

    printf("opening library handle\n");
    h = nfq_open();
    if (!h) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_open()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("unbinding existing nf_queue handler for AF_INET (if any)\n");
    if (nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_unbind_pf()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("binding nfnetlink_queue as nf_queue handler for AF_INET\n");
    if (nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_bind_pf()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("binding this socket to queue '0'\n");
    qh = nfq_create_queue(h, 1, &cb, NULL);
    if (!qh) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error during nfq_create_queue()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("setting copy_packet mode\n");
    if (nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't set packet_copy mode\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fd = nfq_fd(h);

    while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) && rv >= 0) {
        printf("pkt received\n");
        nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
    }

    printf("unbinding from queue 0\n");
    nfq_destroy_queue(qh);

#ifdef INSANE
    /* normally, applications SHOULD NOT issue this command, since
     * it detaches other programs/sockets from AF_INET, too ! */
    printf("unbinding from AF_INET\n");
    nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET);
#endif

    printf("closing library handle\n");
    nfq_close(h);

    exit(0);
}
```

Launching the executable it doesn't receive anything.
I also followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314155/forwarding-packets-to-service-in-same-host-without-using-loopback-network) and tried to use netcat to generate traffic but again i didn't see any packet
Maybe I'm missing something to really interact with filter queues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have. If your firewall lets the packets trough the rules nothing will happen and the packets wont left the kernel space. But if you setting up some rules that send the packets to the user space, your programm will work.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

This line will send all packets from the INPUT with the --in-interface eth0 into the userspace.

Answer (score 2):

libnetfilter_queue is as it's named, a filter. That means, it filters out traffic based on the settings you give it when you create and open the queue.

If you do not send any traffic through this filter, the filter has nothing to work on. How much (what kind of) traffic that goes through this filter, you must set in iptable.

Iptable works as a firewall *into, through* or *out of* your system. Libnetfilter_queue lets you control what to do with the filtered traffic.

Hope this helps you somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Reading that thread I found I haven't added iptables rules... Adding those rules make the trick.

So I always need to set iptables rules to get packets using netfilter library?